# Home server not responding to HTTP

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu, http

I have a home server running Ubuntu 11.10.
It is currently configured to have a static IP address via my router.
I also use a Dynamic DNS service built into the router to update my domain name to point to that statically assigned domain name.

I can access the server via SSH using either the internal IP address or the domain name.

However, when I tried to access it via a browser, it says it cannot connect.
I even tried to read it from the local computer using `wget localhost` and that says connection refused.

I then used `sudo netstat -lep --tcp` and there was no apache2 in the output.
I don't know what its doing now.

I have apache2 installed, have restarted it, rebooted my computer and even reinstalled it.

Checking the logs, I see the following error:

> /usr/sbin/apache2: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_declare_long_constant

Comment: Have you started Apache? Did you even install Apache?

Comment: Yes I have. I updated the question.

Comment: Sounds like Apache isn't running - try to start Apache with `service apache2 start`, and see if there's anything interesting in the error log in `/var/log/apache2/`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden, thanks. I updated the question with the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fast way to test if apache is running 
 `ps -C httpd`  
if you have nmap installed see if the port is  open
 `nmap -p 80 127.0.0.1` if this returns `80/tcp open httpd` the problem is in your routing

see bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57855 , for this error looks like a version mismatch apache php-pdo mysql.so module

Comment: Thanks. I removed the pecl installed pdo library. I don't know if I'll need it anytime soon